# Azure Media Service Channel Creation issue with REST API

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-media-services

I am facing some issue with channel creation service in Azure Media service. I am getting following error message. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the naming convention in [REST documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783458.aspx).

Here is the naming convention for Channel:

- Must be unique within your Media Services account.
- Maximum length = 32 characters.
- Cannot contain spaces.
- Hyphens and alphanumeric characters only.
- Cannot begin or end with a hyphen.

Comment: We gave up Azure lack of doc support moved to WOWZA